# Stop and restart timer task in Android

Tags: java, android, timertask

I need to stop current running timer Task and restart it with a different delay. I tried several ways but nothing works properly. When I use the following code, TimerTask is going to run in both delays.

```
public void restUploadInterval(long newDelay) {
        timerRealData.cancel();
        timerRealData.purge();
        mMqttSupporter = MqttSupporter.getInstance();
        Timer timerRealData = new Timer();
        delay = newDelay;
        UploadingTask uploadingTask = new UploadingTask();
        timerRealData.scheduleAtFixedRate(uploadingTask, delay, delay);
    }
```

Please let me know how can I stop current timer task and run it again with a different delay.

Comment: If you create a new instance of timer task class then multiple instances of timer task will run in the background. So instead of creating new object use the same object for new timer task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as you did.

To restart a Timer with a different timing, you need to cancel() the old timer and create a new one.

Your code probably is not working just because you are hiding the member variable **timerRealData** with a local variable with the same name.

Try to change:

> Timer timerRealData = new Timer();

with

> timerRealData = new Timer();

and it should work.